# AWS AppSync multiple subscriptions in same view controller not working - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Just FYI I posted this question [originally](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=275399&tstart=0) in the AWS AppSync forum (in case in the future AWS answers it).

I have been trying to make a simple Posts app like the one in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html) but I have found no documentation or guides that handle multiple subscriptions in one view controller.

Three mutations: onCreatePost, onUpdatePost, onDeletePost
(and of course three subscriptions to those mutations)

In Xcode, I have three functions called during viewDidLoad(): subscribeToNewPosts(), subscribeToUpdatedPosts(), subscribeToDeletedPosts()

Each subscription function works and creates a subscription with the correct functionality and updates the table view accordingly **if used alone**. But, if called one after the other, only the last subscription will actually receive data and update the table view. I put a breakpoint to check out topicSubscribersDictionary in AppSyncMQTTClient.swift after subscribing to all three mutations

```
func startNewSubscription(subscriptionInfo: AWSSubscriptionInfo) {
        var topicQueue = [String]()
        let mqttClient = MQTTClient<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
        mqttClient.clientDelegate = self
        for topic in subscriptionInfo.topics {
            if topicSubscribersDictionary[topic] != nil {
                // if the client wants subscriptions and is allowed we add it to list of subscribe
                topicQueue.append(topic)
            }
        }
        mqttClients.append(mqttClient)
        mqttClientsWithTopics[mqttClient] = topicQueue
        mqttClient.connect(withClientId: subscriptionInfo.clientId, toHost: subscriptionInfo.url, statusCallback: nil)
    }
```

and all three subscriptions are in fact in the dictionary...

Do I need multiple instances of appSyncClient, one for each subscription? Is it a problem with the schema design?

[schema.graphql](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsforumuploads/Posts/iOS+-+Multiple+subscriptions+in+same+view+controller/schema.graphql)

[schema.json](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsforumuploads/Posts/iOS+-+Multiple+subscriptions+in+same+view+controller/schema.json)

[mutations.graphql](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsforumuploads/Posts/iOS+-+Multiple+subscriptions+in+same+view+controller/mutations.graphql)

[queries.graphql](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsforumuploads/Posts/iOS+-+Multiple+subscriptions+in+same+view+controller/queries.graphql)

[subscriptions.graphql](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsforumuploads/Posts/iOS+-+Multiple+subscriptions+in+same+view+controller/subscriptions.graphql)

Example use case: simple chat app. New conversation started = OnCreatePostSubscription; new incoming message in that conversation = OnUpdatePostSubscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `API Key` for authorization in `AppSync`? If you are using `API Key` only one subscription is supported by the SDK at this point. Could you switch to `IAM` (Cognito Identity) or `Cognito UserPools` based auth and see if multiple subscriptions work for you?

Comment: This was it. I switched to Cognito Identity auth and it works (I have yet to try it with User Pools, which is what I want to use). It was very difficult figuring out how to get the permissions to work correctly without scouring the internet for answered questions. I know you guys always catch flack for your iOS documentation, but I will say you answer AWS forums / StackOverflow questions pretty quickly. For anyone reading this, make sure your IAM Roles include an Allow for your AppSync API resource.

Comment: By the way, got UserPools to work! Only problem still is S3. The --add-s3-wrapper flag for codegen is broken as of this writing. S3Object class is not created. So close!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? The code generator should work with the flag you specified above. Have you defined the schema as suggested in the docs? The type names have to match exactly for the generator to work.

Comment: After updating the S3Object to be a fragment in the .graphql files, as you instructed in your AWS forum reply and as per the instructions on the githhub.io page, everything works as expected. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have several subscriptions working with `API Key` by replacing the call `startSubscriptions` to `startNewSubscription` inside `AWSAppSyncSubscriptionWatcher`

```
if let subscriptionInfo = subscriptionResult.subscrptionInfo {
    self.subscriptionTopic = subscriptionResult.newTopics
    self.client?.addWatcher(watcher: self, topics: subscriptionResult.newTopics!, identifier: self.uniqueIdentifier)
    //self.client?.startSubscriptions(subscriptionInfo: subscriptionInfo)
    subscriptionInfo.forEach { self.client?.startNewSubscription(subscriptionInfo: $0) }
}
```

Couldn't find any side effect with this approach yet, apart from requiring to fork the iOS SKD

Comment: strange I'm also able to implement multiple subs with api key.

Comment: It was a limitation in previous versions, but since the iOS SDK `2.6.22`, you can have multiple subscriptions while authenticating via `API Key`.

Comment: Hi @dreamBegin, you can a mention to it in the project change log. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#enhancements