# Subscriptions with AWS AppSync using IAM in Android app

Tags: android, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I'm using the new AWS AppSync service inside an Android app, with IAM authentication (access key and secret key), so that users can share their locations in real-time from Google Map API.
For that, I created a subscription that works fine in queries console of AppSync.
But when I implemented the subscription in my app, it does not work properly.

Here is a use case :

1. user A access to the map, see his location that it send to AppSync service via a GraphQL subscription
2. user B does the same thing.
3. user A send his last location
4. user B receive it, and user A appear on the user B map
5. user B send his last location, but user A never receive it

If user A quit the map and reopen it, a GraphQL subscription is also reopen, he receive the last user B location sent after his subscription.

At the beginning, I had two GraphQL subscriptions with API Key authentication, but the real-time did not work.
After removing only a subscription, following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49242267/4862232, all works fine.

But since I changed the authentication method, I have troubles, here is the code :

```
    AWSAppSyncClient client = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
            .context(context)
            .serverUrl(APPSYNC_ENDPOINT)
            .region(APPSYNC_REGION)
            .credentialsProvider(new StaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(APPSYNC_ACCESS_KEY, APPSYNC_SECRET_KEY)))
            .defaultResponseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.NETWORK_FIRST)
            .build();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: @Karthikeyan, not yet, I found another solution by requesting my GraphQL locations query every X seconds :-( Shortly I will upgrade to the latest SDK version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You can also post on our Github forum where we may be able to engage better with the app sync community. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android